# How to generate mpd (MPEG Dash manifest) file in code level

Tags: node.js, mpeg-dash, mp4box

How to create MPEG Dash (mpd) file in code level.I couldn't found a way to do this.
It's better to have a node js sample.
I can do it in command line. I used MP4Box tool
But I need to do it in my node js application.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you probably want to create a DASH stream rather than just a manifest file - the manifest file would not be of interest generally without the media streams it indexes to.

This is actually not trivial, especially as there are so many options within the DASH spec and different formats possible within the manifest - e.g. segment timeline, template etc.

It is probably easiest to look at an openesource example of a packager to get a feel for what is involved - you may even find you can just use one as is. One of the most popular is Shaka Packager:

- https://github.com/google/shaka-packager

The documentation for the Shaka Packager includes the following architecture diagrams which may give you a feel for how the manifest creation is tied into the overall packaging work:

[image]

Comment: I'm using shakaplayer, I need to create MPEG-Dash file manually rather than using MP4Box tool.Simple idea is I need to create this mpd file in node js side